# Treating lowercase and uppercase as the same in database search

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase application and I want to be able to search for user but the problem I am having is if the database value is `hello`, if user inputs `hello` in the search bar it returns `true` but if `Hello`, it returns false. I want to be able to treat lowercase and uppercase as the same so even if a user typed `hElLo`, it returns true. below is my code.

```
func fsFindUser(q user: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {

        let userRef = fsRef.collection(USERS_REF)
        let query = userRef.whereField("user", isEqualTo: user)

        query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("Error getting document: \(error)")
            } else if (snapshot?.isEmpty)! {

                completion(false)

            } else {
                completion(true)

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is you store two sets of data in your node; one used for queries that's lowercased and the other used for display

```
users
  uid_0
    queryable: "mcdonald"
    display: "McDonald"
  uid_1
    queryable: "van winkle"
    display: "Van Winkle"
```

Comment: this makes a lot of sense. so I just have to search with queryable